# mongoose lean object type is incorrect

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a data model defined:

```
type MapData = {
    coordinates: [number, number][]; // coordinates consists of an array of [x,y] on the map
}

type MapDataDocument = MapData & mongoose.Document;


const mapDataSchema= new mongoose.Schema(
{coordinates: { type: [[Number, Number]], default: [] }}, { collection: 'mapData' });

export default mongoose.model<MapDataDocument>('mapData', mapDataSchema);
```

When I am fetching it with lean:

```
const mapDataResults:MapDataDocument[] = mapData.find().lean(); //mapData is Model<MapDataDocument, {}, {}>
```

This will give an error on build as:

```
Argument of type 'Pick<_LeanDocument<MapDataDocument>, ... 14 more ' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapDataDocument[]'.
 Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1
```

I don't have any definition of number[], I guess the `.lean` inferred the types incorrectly?

I can probably solve this problem by changing the coordinates' type definition to `number[][]` but I want to keep `[number, number]` as it pertains business knowledge.

What is the way to address the typing issue?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the documentation, I found that in `lean()` function, I can also provide a type to it: `lean<MapData>()` Which will then change the returned type to `MapData`.